# How do i add values of a certain key from two arrays into one new array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to amalgamate some notices into an overall array.

```
   array today = array( 
'keya' => '11',
'keyb' => 'string',
'notice' => 'Visitor Arrives at 3pm',
'keyd' => '44',
...
);

array general = array( 
'keya' => '1',
'notice' => 'Fire Alarms Tested This Week'
);
```

I want to have a new array called $general_notice which merges the $today['notice'] with $general['notice'].

I can't understand what to do using operators or array_merge as i only one to merge the data of a particular key...

NB $general may have multiple rows ie multiple notices...

I think i cant use array_merge because the arrays are multi-dimensional.

EG:

```
//1st array with lots of data but the data belonging to the 'notice' key is what i'm interested in.
array $today = [0]('id'=>'1','lotsOfKeys'=>"lots of values,'notice'="Visitor arrives at 3pm");

array $general = [0]('id'=> '1', 'notice' = "Fire Alarms Tested This Week"),
                 [1]('id'=> '2', 'notice' = "Blue Shift working");
```

The desired result is:

```
$notices = ("Visitor arrives at 3pm", "Fire Alarms Tested This Week", "Blue Shift Working");
```

Comment: add programming language tag and the desired result

Comment: @Tom Could you please add your desired result and could you also check if the programming language tag is right as well?

Comment: You can easily use plus sign. Check here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fd22df66f111277062f9aa39acc8a5b4f2965d56

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using arrays with keys and each array can't have duplicate keys, your desired result would be as simple as:

```
array general_notice = array($today['notice'], $general['notice']);
```

unless you have a two dimensional array of arrays, for example:

```
array general = array(
     array( 
         'keya' => '11',
         'keyb' => 'string',
         'notice' => 'Visitor Arrives at 3pm',
         'keyd' => '44'
      ),
      array( 
          'keya' => '1',
          'notice' => 'Fire Alarms Tested This Week'
      ),
      ...
);
```

In that case, you would need to loop though the notices array and push desired values to a new one like so. You can repeat the loop for each array you want to append to the `general_notice` array:

```
array general_notice = array();
foreach ($general as $value) {
    array_push($general_notice, $value['notice'] );
}
```

You can also append any single dimensional arrays as follows

```
array_push($general_notice, $today['notice']);
```

Comment: but where does the $today array come in?

Comment: ok, now I see that both arrays are two dimensional, you can repeat the loop for each array you ant to add to the `general_notice`

Comment: Thanks Ernis - I'm much closer now as the $general values are inserted sequentially into the new array. HOWEVER, $today value doesn't go in for some reason and I have lots of strange values with single characters etc.  The $general has multiple rows.  $today has one.  I'm still trying to debug

Comment: I think that is because $today is not a two dimensional array. Can you vertify that today always have only a single notice? In that case just add it without loop
`array_push($general_notice, $today['notice'] ); `

Comment: Great thanks Ernis - that solved it.  Many thanks - array_merge was my red herring.

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear, what do you mean by merging them? Are you trying to concatenate the values of the keys based on both arrays having the same key?

Comment: Yes - that's right.  Have a new array that contains just the values of all of the notices